# How to switch the main layout in Blazor?

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

I am trying to archive it when the user press on the Login link at the upper left link containing login:

[image]

But instead, I am receiving this:

[image]

In other words: I'd like to go to a page without the nav bars of the main layout. How to archive it ?

**MainLayout.razor**

```
inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="page">
  <div class="sidebar">
      <NavMenu />
  </div>

  <div class="main">
    <div class="top-row px-4">
        <a href="/login" target="_blank" class="ml-md-auto">Login</a>
    </div>
    <div class="content px-4">
        @Body
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Login.razor**

```
@page "/login"
<style>
#login .container #login-row #login-column #login-box {
    margin-top: 120px;
    max-width: 600px;
    height: 320px;
    border: 1px solid #9C9C9C;
    background-color: #EAEAEA;
 }

    #login .container #login-row #login-column #login-box #login-form {
        padding: 20px;
    }

        #login .container #login-row #login-column #login-box #login-form #register-link {
            margin-top: -85px;
        }
</style>
<div id="login">
    <h3 class="text-center text-white pt-5">Login form</h3>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="login-row" class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <div id="login-column" class="col-md-6">
                <div id="login-box" class="col-md-12">
                    <form id="login-form" class="form" action="" method="post">
                        <h3 class="text-center text-info">Login</h3>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="username" class="text-info">Username:</label><br>
                            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password" class="text-info">Password:</label><br>
                            <input type="text" name="password" id="password" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="remember-me" class="text-info"><span>Remember me</span> <span><input id="remember-me" name="remember-me" type="checkbox"></span></label><br>
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-md" value="submit">
                        </div>
                        <div id="register-link" class="text-right">
                            <a href="#" class="text-info">Register here</a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


@code {

}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can Use the @layout Razor directive set to an EmptyLayout on the top of you login componant

```
@layout EmptyLayout

    **... you componant..**
```

Example of EmptyLayout

```
    @inherits LayoutComponentBase

   <div class="main">    
    <div class="content px-4">
        @Body
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I am sorry.. but can you explain a little better ? I don't know where each thing goes...

Comment: i'm not sure what part you did not get , just add "@layout EmptyLayout " to the top of your Login.razor and create a componant named "EmptyLayout.razor" and put the code in my answer inside

Comment: Thanks !!! This really can do the trick ! Just one more thing: How to programmatically return to the home using the regular layout? I mean: When I press the submit button, if a successfully login, I'd like to return to the normal template at home page.

Comment: you can inject "NavigationManager" in your component like this : 
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
and  on your sumbit button event handler you can navigate to your home page using "NavigationManager.NavigateTo("home ");"